# Android studio dont run an updated app version

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Few weeks ago I finished develop a new app in android studio.
I moved the project folder into a hard-disk, formated my computer and download android studio again.
I have opened the project and run it and it work perfectly, **but** when I do some changes in the code and run it again, its just run the old version and not the updated. No matter what I edit in the code, its does not affect the app.

What can I do?

Comment: Make sure u allready uninstall old app and try to clean your new app n  test..

Answer (score 0):

Are you emulating on your computer or the actual device? If you delete the app off the device and run again maybe that will launch the new version. It seems that android studio is running your old project so somewhere in the run configurations you need to make sure that android studio launches the most recent activity file.

Comment: I have tried all the options and nothing help, and Im running on emulator and a real device.